# Process n items from a list at a time in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Given a list, how do I process *N* items at a time? Ruby has [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method on the `Enumerable` that does this; what would be the Lisp equivalent?

Comment: CL doesn't have anything built-in to do this, but you can easily construct it using SUBSEQ in a loop.

Comment: Using subseq in a loop is probably going to allocate a lot of intermediate storage.  The [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) macro supports this natively with `(loop for ... on ... by ...)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Common Lisp's [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) can be used for this very nicely, as in the following two examples.  The first example loops for `(x y z)` in a list.  However, the default step is `cdr` (`rest`), so if the list is `(1 2 3 4 5)`, you get `(1 2 3)`, `(2 3 4)`, etc., for `(x y z)`.

```
CL-USER> (loop for (x y z) on '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
              do (print (list z y x)))

(3 2 1) 
(4 3 2) 
(5 4 3) 
(6 5 4) 
(7 6 5) 
(8 7 6) 
(9 8 7) 
(10 9 8) 
(11 10 9) 
(12 11 10) 
(NIL 12 11) 
(NIL NIL 12) 
NIL
```

If you do not want the overlap between iterations, specify the stepping function to be something that moves farther down the list.  For instance, if you're pulling three elements at a time, use `cdddr`:

```
CL-USER> (loop for (x y z) on '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12) by 'cdddr
              do (print (list z y x)))
(3 2 1) 
(6 5 4) 
(9 8 7) 
(12 11 10) 
NIL
```

### Implementing partition with this technique

Another answer implemented the counterpart to `each_slice` using an auxiliary function.  However, notice that `partition` (in that sense) is just `each_slice` with the identity function.  This suggests that we should be able to implement it using the idiom above.  The anonymous function

```
(lambda (list)
  (nthcdr n list))
```

is the step function that we need.  Since we do not know how many elements the cells have until run time, we can't bind each element like we did above with `(x y z)`.  We do have to match each tail of the list as we step down and extract the subsequence *n* elements.  Here's a `loop` based implementation of `partition`.

```
CL-USER> (defun partition (list cell-size)
           (loop for cell on list by #'(lambda (list)
                                         (nthcdr cell-size list))
              collecting (subseq cell 0 cell-size)))
PARTITION

CL-USER> (partition '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 2)
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua! Used your second code snippet; needed 2 elts so used cddr. Loving Lisp!

Comment: @rebnoob Glad to hear it!  Common Lisp has a whole lot of functionality packed in the standard, so it's not a bad idea to skim the [table of contents](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm) and sub of the subsections, not to learn everything in detail, but to have an idea what's there, and to know where to look when you want something.  For instance, I had to check the `(loop ... on ... by ...)` syntax to make sure it was right, but I had an idea _where_ to look.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun partition-helper (lst acc x)
  (if (< (length lst) x)
    acc
    (partition-helper (subseq lst x) (cons (subseq lst 0 x) acc) x)))

(defun partition (lst x)
  (reverse (partition-helper lst '() x)))
```

Then you can:

```
[25]> (PARTITION '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 2)
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
```

or:

```
[26]> (PARTITION '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 3)
((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

and then just `mapcar` over the list to process it 2 or 3 elements at a time.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to split your list on a predicate (as opposed to a fixed length sublists), I would have recommended [`nsplit-list`](http://clocc.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/clocc/clocc/raw-file/tip/list.lisp).

For fixed length sublists, you may want to use [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm):

```
(defun by-N (list n fun) 
  (loop for tail on list by (lambda (l) (nthcdr n l)) 
    do (funcall fun (subseq tail 0 (min (length tail) n)))))
(by-n (loop for i from 0 to 20 collect i) 5 #'print)

(0 1 2 3 4) 
(5 6 7 8 9) 
(10 11 12 13 14) 
(15 16 17 18 19) 
(20)
```

Note that this is not very efficient (it scans the list more than necessary and allocates a fresh sublist for passing to `fun`).

The efficient version is more complicated:

```
(defun batch-map (list batch-size function)
  "Call FUNCTION on sublists of LIST of size BATCH-SIZE.
Returns the list of return values of FUNCTION."
  (do ((tail list (cdr end)) end ret (bs1 (1- batch-size)))
      ((endp tail) (nreverse ret))
    (setq end (nthcdr bs1 tail))
    (if (consp end)
        (let ((next (cdr end)))
          (setf (cdr end) nil)
          (unwind-protect (push (funcall function tail) ret)
            (setf (cdr end) next)))
        (push (funcall function tail) ret))))
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are practical and can be used, but I believe none replicates exactly the Ruby's behavior:

```
> 1.upto(7).each_slice(3) { |x, y, z| p [x, y, z] }
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, nil, nil]
```

To emulate Ruby, I believe the proper code is something similar to:

```
CL-USER> (defun each-slice (n list thunk)
  (apply thunk (loop for i below n collect (nth i list)))

  (if (> (length list) n)
      (each-slice n (subseq list n) thunk)))
```

Generates a similar response when called:

```
CL-USER> (each-slice 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) (lambda (x y z) (print (list x y z))))

(1 2 3) 
(4 5 6) 
(7 NIL NIL) 
NIL
```

Comment: the accepted answer's approach already does this: `(loop for (x y z) on '(1 2 3 4) by 'cdddr do (print (list x y z)))` prints `(1 2 3)`
`(4 NIL NIL)` and returns `NIL`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works adding the extra NIL values but requires you to adjust the "by" parameter either using cd*dr or nthcdr inside an extra lambda.

There are also another behavior from Ruby's each_slice which the loop version emulates better... in Ruby if you call each_slice without given a block it will returns an Enumerator instance which can be chained and this can be better emulated using loop and collecting the result.