# How to transform list into sub lists?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

```
((1 2 3)
(2 3 4)
(3 4 5)
(4 5 6))
```

from

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

And what is the type of such operation?

What I tried:

```
(loop
   :with l2 = '()
   :with l1 = '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
   :for i :in l1
   :do (push (subseq l1 0 3) l2))
```

Comment: Just write a loop that uses `SUBSEQ` to get each sublist. I'm not sure what you mean by your second question.

Comment: Reduce a list, pop a list, slice etc.

Comment: It's a sequence of slices. Your specific operation isn't very common, so I don't think there's a name for it.

Comment: It looks this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198677/process-n-items-from-a-list-at-a-time-in-lisp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pushing the same sublist every time through the loop.

You can use `:for sublist on` to loop over successive tails of a list.

And use `:collect` to make a list of all the results, rather than pushing onto your own list

```
(loop
   :for l1 on '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
   :if (>= (length l1) 3)
      :collect (subseq l1 0 3)
   :else 
      :do (loop-finish))
```

Comment: Nice! I've not used `:on` yet. Thank you.

Comment: It was in the question you linked to!

Comment: this is quadratic, because of `(length l1)`.

Comment: it also doesn't stop when possible, and goes on iterating till the list ends.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't fix `(length l1)`, but I added `(loop-finish)` to stop early.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively use `map`:

```
(let ((l '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  (map 'list #'list l (cdr l) (cddr l)))

;; ((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6))
```

You can read it as:

- for list `l` with values `(1 2 3 4 5 6)`
- `map` over the list and its two successive `cdr`s
- by applying `#'list` on the elements of the lists `map` is looping through in parallel
- (stopping when shortest list is used up)
- and collecting the results as/into a `'list`

@WillNess suggested even simpler:

```
(let ((l '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  (mapcar #'list l (cdr l) (cddr l)))
```

thanks! So then we could generalize using only `map` variants:

```
(defun subseqs-of-n (l n)
  (apply #'mapcar #'list (subseq (maplist #'identity l) 0 n)))
```

`(maplist #'identity l)` is equivalent to `(loop for sl on l collect sl)`.
However,

```
(loop for sl on l
      for i from 0 to n
      collect sl)
```

is  better because it stops at n-th round of looping ...

Comment: `(mapcar #'list ...` is simpler, and also works. not for strings though. :)

Comment: @WillNess Thank you! Ah I didn't know that `mapcar` is variadic xD .

Comment: `(apply #'mapcar #'list ...` is one neat famous trick, the one most Lisp-y thing there is about Lisp if you ask me. :) other languages must go through hoops to transpose a list of lists.

Comment: @WillNess Oh yeah, the expression contains some famous lisp words in it `apply` `map` `car` `list` `#'` and does what lisp is really good at! ;) - I wished common lisp would be used more often in wild/real life ...

Comment: I meant [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52190645/849891) specifically. :) (it's in Scheme though, so `list` is function, not a list :) )

Comment: @WillNess Ah this you mean. Yes, by `apply`-ing `map` we  make the list variadic ;) - the functional equivalent to `\`(map ,@args)` in macros, isn't it? What makes variadic macros. And yes, super lispy, indeed ;) .

Comment: But do you know that R has sth very similar? (well R was in its experimental state impemented in scheme. And then one decided to let it be based on `C` but by keeping as much as possible from the lispy underlying structures. `R` thus has `bquote()` and `.()` - the equivalent of `\`` and `,`. It has `do.call()` which is like a `funcall` but the arguments have to be given in a list like `apply` takes. So `do.call(func_name, args)` where `args` must be of the type list.

Comment: well Python also has some `*args` splicing mechanism. maybe JS has something like that too.

Answer (score 3):

First let's define a function `take-n`, which either returns n items or an empty list, if there are not enough items. It will not scan the whole list.

```
(defun take-n (n list)
  (loop repeat n
        when (null list) return (values nil nil)
        collect (pop list)))
```

Then we move this function `take-n` over the list until it returns `NIL`.

```
(defun moving-slice (n list)
  (loop for l on list
        for p = (take-n n l)
        while p
        collect p))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 207 > (moving-slice 3 '(1 2))
NIL

CL-USER 208 > (moving-slice 3 '(1 2 3))
((1 2 3))

CL-USER 209 > (moving-slice 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6) (5 6 7))
```

Comment: That's a neat answer!

Comment: yeah, has a nice functional feeling to it. :) except -- if we're talking slices -- it'd be only natural to have it work on *vectors* as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of Barmar's answer (which should be the accepted one) which is a bit more general and only calls `length` once.

```
(defun successive-leading-parts (l n)
  (loop repeat (1+ (- (length l) n))
        for lt on l
        collect (subseq lt 0 n)))
```

```
> (successive-leading-parts '(1 2 3 4) 3)
((1 2 3) (2 3 4))

> (successive-leading-parts '(1 2 3 4) 2)
((1 2) (2 3) (3 4))
```

Comment: not only is Barmar's code quadratic, it doesn't even stop as soon as possible, so for e.g. (slices 9999 list-of-length-10000) it'll do 10000 iterations instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Or the classical more `C`-like for-loop-ing with indexes to solve it. 
But use it more on strings/vectors but less on lists, because its performance is

- for lists quadratic
- for vectors (strings!) linear, so preferably to be used with them!

credits and thanks to @WillNess who pointed both points out (see comments below).

```
(defun subseqs-of-n (ls n) ;; works on strings, too!
  (loop :for i :from 0 :to (- (length ls) n)
        :collect (subseq ls i (+ i n))))
```

So on vectors/strings use:

```
(subseqs-of-n "gattaca" 5)
;; ("gatta" "attac" "ttaca")
```

Comment: that's needlessly quadratic though.

Comment: @WillNess True, but it works on strings. (That was why I wrote it actually). So not completely needless ;) .

Comment: yeah, I completely forgot about vectors. my bad. :) maybe just mention this problem for lists, in the answer?

Comment: (thanks! ;) - it was - yesterday I wrote some other answer. But then at work needed that tiling function. - I try to use CL at work. And remembered: Ah I wrote sth like this for answering in SO! So it was more coincidence that I came back to that question and added it ;) ).

Comment: it is quadratic on lists but linear on vectors (and [string](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string) is a vector).

Comment: @WillNess Thanks! Again learned more - from you ;) . Thank you!